# Does Ramaze have a Sinatra like "before/after" hooks?

Tags: ruby, ramaze

Wondering if Ramaze has hooks like Sinatra. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their [documentation](http://ramaze.net/documentation/Innate/Helper/Aspect/SingletonMethods.html) tells you that it does. For instance:

```
before(:index, :other) do
    puts 'Executed before specific actions only.'
end

after(:index, :other) do
    puts 'Executed after specific actions only.'
end
```